# QGIS: Attribute table cleared itself

Tags: qgis

I created a line (multi-line string) in QGIS, filled the attribute table with the length of the line. After I extended the line, the attribute table cleared itself (the length column is empty)
Is there a way to update the line information, in this case, the length, instead of clearing it?

Comment: Check out `virtual fields`.

Comment: What you mean by "clearing" ? You entered a number and it disappered, so you it's empty? Either the data file format the layer is saved in does not support editing attributes in QGIS (e.g. KML or gpx files) or you entered a wrong field type - e.g. entering a decimal number to an `integer` or `boolean` field.

Comment: You need to provide more information on your workflow (like did you save after entering the length, ?) with the exact steep you took. Without these informations we can't know what went wrong. Also note that attribute do not auto update (modifying the geometry of the line by extending it wont change the length that you manually entered as attribute, if you want to have auto-updating length see, as per @Erik suggestion, virtual fields)